# Integral shrinks with measure of the set

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I would like to prove the following:

My idea is to pass to a function $f$ in $L^1$ that bounds all the $f_n$ (whose existence is guaranteed because the sequence is Cauchy) and show that the size of the integral of $f$ can be made small by integrating over a sequence of sets with measure going to zero. However, I'm not sure if this is equivalent to solving the above problem. How should I proceed?

Comment: What about $n$, which quantifier (exists/for all) do you use there?

Comment: @SBF For all, I think. That's why I tried bounding the f_n's with a single f.

Comment: Have you tried that in case $f_n = f$?

Comment: Assuming the sequence is constant, you mean?

Comment: Yes, in that case

Comment: My only idea is to maybe use the strategy I described. For any sequence of sets with measure going to zero, I could show that integrating over them makes the integral go to zero...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The important things here are the Cauchy criterion and the absolute continuity of a *fixed* Lebesgue integrable function.

Let $\epsilon > 0$. Because $\{f_n\}$ is Cauchy, there is $N(\epsilon)$ so that if $n > N$, $\int |f_n-f_N|<\epsilon/2$. Now for any $n > N$, and measurable set $B$, $\int_B|f_n| \le \int_B |f_n-f_N| + \int_B |f_N| < \epsilon/2 + \int_B|f_N|$. Now choose $\delta>0$ such that if $\mu(B)<\delta$, we have $\int_B|f_N|<\epsilon/2$ (this $\delta$ exists because $f_N\in L^1$). For this choice of $\delta$, it follows that for $n > N$, and any $B$ measurable, we have $\int_B|f_n|<\epsilon$.

Next choose $\delta'=\delta'(N)$ so small that for each of the functions $f_1,\dots,f_N$, for each measurable set $B$ with $\mu(B)<\delta'$, we have  $\int_B|f_j|< \epsilon$. Now it suffices to take the minimum of $\delta$ and $\delta'$.

---

Added: The main lemma about absolute continuity we used is the following.

**Lemma.** If $f\in L^1(d\mu)$, then for each $\epsilon>0$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that if $\mu(B)<\delta$, then $\int_B|f|\,d\mu<\epsilon$.

*Proof sketch.*  Consider for each $M$ the level set $E_M = \{x:|f(x)|>M\}$. For any measurable set $B$, consider $\int_B |f| \le \int_{E_M}|f| + \int_{B\cap E_M^\complement}|f|$. First choose $M$ sufficiently large so that the first integral is $<\epsilon/2$. Then choose $\delta$ so small (depending on $M$, and hence on $\epsilon$) that if $\mu(B)<\delta$, the second integral is less than $\epsilon/2$.

Comment: Thanks! Can you expand on why $\delta$ exists? I agree that there exists a B with small enough measure to make the integral small, but why are we guaranteed a single $\delta$ so that any B with measure smaller than that makes the integral less than $\epsilon/2$?

Comment: @Marble: I added some more discussion about why $\delta$ exists with some steps for you to fill in.

Comment: @Marble: You should also be aware that the limit function $f$ that we used does not necessarily pointwise bound the functions $f_n$. Also in many problems in Lebesgue integration and measure theory, the level sets $E_M$ we used here as well as sets of the form $\{x: a<|f(x)|\le b\}$ are very fundamental, and they get used as components in many proofs.

Comment: Following up on this. I really cannot seem to convince myself that $\int_{E_M}|f|$ can be made small. It seems like assuming what we're trying to prove...

Comment: @Marble: it isn’t at all the same as assuming what’s been asked to prove because $E_M$ are fixed measurable sets depending on the parameter $M$, while the claim is about arbitrary measurable sets with small measure. Anyway, since $f\in L^1$, $|f|<\infty$ a.e. In particular $f\chi_{E_M}$ converges to 0 almost surely. Use the dominated convergence theorem to conclude. An alternative is to use the monotone convergence theorem applied to the sequence $|f|\chi_{E_M^\complement}$ together with the fact $f$ is integrable. Hopefully that is helpful for you.